# Visual Studio Pre-build Event/Post-build Events Working Directory

Tags: visual-studio, build, post-build-event, working-directory, pre-build-event

It's not clear from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx) what the working directory is for pre-build or post-build events in Visual Studio. What is it? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The working directory is the bin directory of the project.

I was unable to find documentation, but I tested this by making a post build event that made a directory. Then I checked where it was created.

Comment: More specifically, it is `bin\$(ConfigurationName)\netcoreapp1.1` (or whatever your sdk resolves to).

Answer (score 10):

For future reference, to find the execution directory, you could also enter:

**"start cd"**

in the Pre-Build event command line area.

This will open a command prompt in the current path after saving and triggering a build.

Also, the directory will be pointing in the \bin\debug|release.

Comment: +1 I do not have a bin directory, but with this I was able to discover that the Pre-Build event's working directory is the one containing my *.vcxproj file.